# Column by column reading of data from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, file

Is it possible to read data from a file column by column instead of reading row by row in C++? I have data in a file which I want them to be read column by column and to be stored in an array in that order. Any help would be appreciated. THanks!

Comment: you could try to change the delimiter of the `getline` function see e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19107439/c-getline-multiple-variable-types-using-comma-as-delimiter)

Comment: also consider to have a look on [how to ask a good questions on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make your questions better

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way. Data such as text in a text file is not represented by rows and columns, it's generally all strung together and separated by control characters such as `\s`, `\t`, `\r\n` or just `\n`. Whatever you use to parse the data looks for those control characters and returns the bytes in between. When it comes to parsing your column by column data into an array you just need to mess with your nested for loop structure.

Comment: what @Jonny Henly said in simpler words: Files have no rows or columns, you can only read them from the beginning till the end

Comment: @tobi303 thanks, that's what I was going for but wasn't sure how to word it.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to read column by column because you can fill an array row by row or column by column, it doesnt matter for the array (as pointed out be Jonny Henly in his comment):

pseudo code:

"read rows":

```
data[size][size];
for (int row=0;row<size;row++)
    for (int col=0;col<size;col++)
        inputFile >> data[row][col];
```

"read columns": (i.e. `data` is transposed of the file contents)

```
data[size][size];
for (int col=0;col<size;col++)
    for (int row=0;row<size;row++)
        inputFile >> data[row][col];
```